# The [printing] tag is full of irrelevant questions that were redirected from [print]. How can we fix it?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I have noticed that [printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printing) is **full** of questions that are about built-in functionality for displaying messages on the standard output. Mainly these are Python questions about the built-in `print` function (or in really old questions, statement); some are Java questions involving `System.out.print` (and `println`). In other languages where the functionality is named differently, it is much less common, but does happen on occasion.

It seems self-evident that this happens because people try to tag their question about how to use the built-in `print` - which, as I've tested, gets redirected to `printing`. The resulting questions then float, irrelevant, among questions that correctly use the tag (to talk about sending data to a printer to produce a physical image).

C programmers [get their own `printf` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+printf); Python questions [are common enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+printing) - not as many, but they keep coming in.

I would like to be able to use better tags for these Python questions, especially on older canonical targets such as [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136) or [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285). Right now I have settled for the much uglier [output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/output), which I don't think is going to help people find them, but is probably still better than e.g. [io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io).

I would like to see something done about this, but I don't have any good ideas.

Comment: Why not just remove that tag? What benefit do we gain over just having the relevant language tag?

Comment: Sorry; which tag do you mean by "that" tag? `printing` is a language-agnostic tag about sending data to a printer, and it does not have language-specific versions. Oh, did you mean "untag the questions that use the `printing` tag incorrectly"? There are a lot, and they will keep coming back because of the redirect. Separately, I want a tag that makes it easier to find canonicals like the ones I highlighted.

Comment: Yes, the printing tag. Why not just remove it from questions that aren't about printing, _without_ replacement. And printf, for that matter, this is all just basic use of the relevant languages that doesn't need further meta tagging.

Comment: Why do we have this tag? Can't we just use [tag:printers]? The [printing] tag wiki makes it very confusing.

Comment: "this is all just basic use of the relevant languages that doesn't need further meta tagging" If you think those are "meta tags" then there is a *lot* out there that must irritate you. I see things like `loop` and `function` and `if-statement` constantly.

Comment: Yes, those are also utterly pointless and I remove them when editing.

Comment: Both print and printing suffers heavily from ambiguity, though; aside printing to a piece of paper, there's printing to the console or any other type of stream, printing to pdf or other pseudo-printers, Printers as a class in Java and presumably other languages, that also have nothing to do with paper printers, and not to forget about 3D printers. in the case of print() specifically, that's likely to be (ab)used for a number of languages, making the tag relatively useless standalone